# Crawling With Multiple EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-crawler

I've got a crawling process I've written in python that I am running on an ec2 instance on amazon.  I've written the crawler so that it reports back to a separate "hub" instance with it's results. The hub processes the results of the crawler and the crawler is free to keep crawling. What I had in mind with this crawling instance is that it would be easy to clone several instances of the crawler, having each of them report back to the hub for processing.

So, at this point, I have one hub and 8 separate crawlers (all on their own instances) continually crawling and reporting back in etc.

I was thinking with the small, separate crawlers:

1. There is redundancy so if one crawler gets hung up, the rest of the crawlers can keep working.
2. (This is an assumption) I have better network utilization if each crawler has it's own independent ip.
3. I can spin up several crawlers or scale down depending on my current needs.

My question is; Is this efficient? Would I be better off spinning up a larger instance and somehow splitting up the network utilization?

Thank you in advance for your input.  Please forgive me if this is off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my view on your question.

(1) There is redundancy so if one crawler gets hung up, the rest of the crawlers can keep working.

> set with auto-scaling group to manage these crawler instances.

(2) (This is an assumption) I have better network utilization if each crawler has its own independent ip.

> Yes, ec2 instance can have its own public and private ip if created in public subnets. Within one region, you can set to launch the instances on different Available Zone (for example, us-west-2 region has three AZs). With that, you can spread the network usage.

(3) I can spin up several crawlers or scale down depending on my current needs.

> with auto-scaling group, you should be easy to control this ***

My question is; Is this efficient?

*** If you can, set ec2 instances in different regions (US, EU, Asia, etc)  to reduce latency for some websites. ***

Would I be better off spinning up a larger instance and somehow splitting up the network utilization?

*** in your case, separate smaller instances should be a better solution, it also saves much money for you. Maybe you can also think to use `spot instance` for these crawlers. to save more ***

Comment: Smaller instances probably will be a better solution, but larger instances have more network (so presumably, more Internet) bandwidth.  Also: *Yes, every ec2 instance has its own public and private ip.* is only universally true in EC2-Classic, not necessarily so in VPC. Not all AWS accounts have access to EC2-Classic in every region; some are VPC only. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#detecting-platform

Comment: Thank you for your additional comments.